# How can I import modules to Python in Processing?

Tags: python, processing

I am testing `Processing` Python implementation, but I can't seem to find a way to import some modules to it.

For this example I am trying to import the `ib` module and I get:

```
ImportError: No module named ib
```

Even though when I go to python in Terminal and import it, it works just fine.

Also when I try to import some other modules to Processing like the following

```
from threading import RLock
```

It works just fine.

Any idea why `Processing` might be reading some of the modules and some not?

Any tip will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Processing uses its own Python interpreter. You should be able to use `sys.executable` to find the path of the current Python interpreter, so within your Processing REPL, do:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If that doesn't output the location of your system Python (on Windows: usually `C:\PythonXY` where XY is your Python version) then you know that's the problem. A Python interpreter can't find modules that weren't installed to *its* folder!

A possible solution in that case is to install truly *global* modules to a separate directory and point your `PYTHONPATH` env var at that directory. Be careful with this, though, if you have both Python3 and Python2 on your system.

Comment: Looks you are right. When I print sys.executable I get "None". I wonder if there is anyway to force a python path within the script instead of creating an env. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JordanBelf [this link might be helpful](https://github.com/jdf/processing.py/wiki/Python-Mode-for-Processing:-FAQ)